# Store find by id on column that return x_id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I made an API that return in a JSON format a catalog. The problem is that the "id" is not named "id", but "catalog_id". When I do :

```
return this.store.find('catalog', 1);
```

* Note that the I have set my adapter to :

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'web/app_dev.php'
});
```

Here's what my api returns:

[image]

Unfortunatly, Ember-data translate this into :
[image]

EDIT: this image is too small, here's the link for full size : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdVDk.png

Any idea how I can fix this issue? I would like not to rename my "category_id" into "id". I would have to do lots of refactoring and I don't want this.

Cheers.

EDIT #2: Note that my console return the following error : Assertion failed: You must include an `id` in a hash passed to `push`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id key name is defined by the `primaryKey` propety from `RESTSerializer`. You can override this using:

```
App.CatalogSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({ 
    primaryKey: 'catalog_id' 
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You again :) Thanks alot.